# Python: Class defined inside another Class

Tags: python, class

I need a class in which I can define other classes. For example, let's say you have a class called "Shapes", with this class you can create objects that are "Shapes". circle, square, etc. What I want to be able to do is, inside of "Shapes", create other classes, for instance, circle or square. Every "subclass" will have the same variables, eg. color, surface area, etc. So at the end of the day I want to define a blue circle called 'Tommy' that has a surface area of 78.5398163397 u^2

In my mind it looks like this:

```
class Shapes():
    def __init__(self, myclassname):
        class myclassname():
            def __init__(self, color, surf_area):
                self.color = color
                self.surf_area = surf_area
```

So to use this you would go:

```
Circle = Shapes(Circle)
Tommy = Circle(blue, 78.5398163397)
```

I've tried this, it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Edit:

Some seem confused, i don't want a circle or square or triangle class hardcoded into the program, I want to be able to define a new shape during runtime.

Edit no.2:

I'm not looking for inheritence. basically all I want is to be able to give a class a variable name, eg.

```
var = Input('Enter class name')
class var(): # var as in the variable not a class called var
    normal class stuff
```

Comment: What you want is called [inheritance](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance), you may want to read more about [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) before using it in a specific language

Comment: Surface area is a pretty simplistic common property. In practice each shape would probably have a bunch of unique properties, no? So one common class definition probably won't be of much use. Why not simply define a bunch of subclasses inheriting from `Shape` with their own individual implementation?

Comment: maybe what you want to have is inheritance, reflect the real world concept well.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with giving a class a variable name? Why not simply make that name a variable property of a general class, e.g. `Shape('circle', 'blue', whatever=42)`. It basically achieves the same thing without being insane.

Comment: Nested classes are of no to, in some extreme cases, very little use. They are likely _not_ what you want.

You probably can do fine with one base `Shape` class and an ordinary function that can dynamically create classes that inherit from shape - but there is no need for this to be nested inside shape.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a factory pattern.

Quick google search gives:

```
# Factory/shapefact1/ShapeFactory1.py
# A simple static factory method.
from __future__ import generators
import random

class Shape(object):
    # Create based on class name:
    def factory(type):
        #return eval(type + "()")
        if type == "Circle": return Circle()
        if type == "Square": return Square()
        assert 0, "Bad shape creation: " + type
    factory = staticmethod(factory)

class Circle(Shape):
    def draw(self): print("Circle.draw")
    def erase(self): print("Circle.erase")

class Square(Shape):
    def draw(self): print("Square.draw")
    def erase(self): print("Square.erase")

# Generate shape name strings:
def shapeNameGen(n):
    types = Shape.__subclasses__()
    for i in range(n):
        yield random.choice(types).__name__

shapes = \
  [ Shape.factory(i) for i in shapeNameGen(7)]

for shape in shapes:
    shape.draw()
    shape.erase()
```

Credits to http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html

Comment: No, that isn't what they want. They say they need a "class inside another class", but from the description they are clearly looking for simple inheritance.

Comment: As I said before, I need to be able to add a new shape, say a square, during runtime, I don't want it hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override __new__ method instead as __init__ cannot return any value, also you can use [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function to construct new class dynamically,:

```
class Shapes(object):

    def __new__(cls, class_name):
        def default_init(self, color, surf_area):
            self.color = color
            self.surf_area = surf_area
        return type(class_name, (Shapes,),
                {'__init__': default_init, '__new__': super(Shapes, 
cls).__new__})

# Usage:
Circle = Shapes('Circle')
Tommy = Circle('blue', 78.5398163397)

print vars(Tommy)
# {'color': 'blue', 'surf_area': 78.5398163397}
```

Alternatively the same behaviour, but without dynamic class creation may be achieved with the class inheritance and mapping dictionary which points to classes by keys:

```
class Shape(object):
    """ Base class for shapes. """
    pass

class Circle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, color, surf_area):
        self.color = color
        self.surf_area = surf_area

class Triangle(Shape):pass


shapes = {
    'circle': Circle,
    'triangle': Triangle,
}

circle = shapes['circle']('blue', 78.5398163397)
```

Comment: I need to be able to add a new shape, say a square, during runtime, I don't want it hardcoded.

Comment: @Rick What good is making up a new shape at runtime if it essentially only differs in name, since you cannot possibly define shape-specific properties as well? Are you going to define shapes classes by user input? Otherwise you'll have a set of shapes known in advance which you can define in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this:

```
class Shape(object):
    _registry = {}
    def __new__(cls, name):
        if name in cls._registry:
            return cls._registry[name]
        class Proto(object):
            def __init__(self, color, surf_area):
                self.color = color
                self.surf_area = surf_area
        Proto.__name__ = name
        cls._registry[name] = Proto
        return Proto
```

But I don't see the point at all - your "dynamic" classes have no behaviour at all and all have the exact same attribute set, so you could just use one single class instead and get exactly the same behaviour:

```
class Shape(object):
    def __init__(self, typename, color, surf_area):
        self.typename = typename
        self.color = color
        self.surf_area = surf_area
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Shape({}) at {}>".format(self.typename, id(self))

blue_circle = Shape("Circle", "blue", 78.4222)
```

This [looks like a XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me, you should perhaps tell more about the real problem you're trying to solve with this instead.